# Develop Workflow diagrams for Acitivi

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, workflow, activiti

I need to make a project with workflow diagrams BPMN in Eclipse and I wonder what tool to use for Eclipse to  make easy  the diagrams and to deployment in Activiti.

I see few tools but there is much more configuration for xml files.

I just wanna draw the diagrams and set few things.

Comment: You need to checkout [Activiti Eclipse Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ACT/Activiti+BPMN+2.0+Eclipse+Plugin)